# Convert Application to Applets

Tags: java, applet, web-deployment

I have heard and read a lot of people putting down Java Applets. I have a java a application written for the desktop. But with a few lines of code, I can deploy my application to the web as an Applet? I fail to see what is so bad about them. Can anyone inform me why simply converting my application to an applet is a bad deployment idea?

Comment: Some groups are completely embracing the Java applet with much success: http://pivot.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a java a application written for the desktop. But with a few lines of code, I can deploy my application to the web as an Applet?

With a few lines of JNLP, you can launch your (J)Frame based project directly from a web site using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> ..Can anyone inform me why simply converting my application to an applet is a bad deployment idea?

'Browsers'.  As you probably realize, an applet is a guest in a web page that is rendered by a browser.  Browser/JRE/applet interaction bugs are the bane of an applet developer.  There is a new one every other week.  Avoid the browser, and most of the problems are solved in a stroke.

I deploy applets on my site, though I generally only make an applet when the web page can bring something to the applet.  E.G. there is a properties applet that is configured using JavaScript.

But my general advice is, avoid applets if at all possible.

Comment: Java web start is an interesting suggestion. The application is a content management system. I was thinking applet because it would give the feel of other web based content management systems because it would be running in the browser.

Comment: OK.  I hear you.  Perhaps the best option is to go for an *embedded* applet that is configured/launched using JWS.  Any app. (applet or frame) launched using JWS has access to the JNLP API.  The JNLP API provides functionality for even sand-boxed apps. to access the local file system.  Check my demo. of the JNLP API FileContents at (http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't see anything inherently bad about applets.

Applets do have restricted security permissions, so you will have less access to the system in question. If you're deploying over the web, though, I wouldn't expect this to be a big problem.

Comment: Yea, the security permissions would be an issue. I need access to the file system. But, I suppose I could just sign it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with Java applets. We have apps deployed as both JWS desktop applications and as applets.

Applets do have a few shortcomings, however.

First, a page with an applet forces the Java VM to start up if it isn't already running; this can cause noticeable lags for users on many systems. (I think this might be a source of some of the negativity for applets. They were being (over)used on web pages for things like navigation bars that can be easily handled with DHTML with much less overhead.)

Secondly, an applet in a browser tends to be a more constrained execution environment. Unless you are using JWS, you don't have access to the file system, printing, and many other resources. You can't open connections except back to the server where the applet came from. You generally can't easily resize the applet window. There are probably other issues as well.

I'm sure others will point out more shortcomings. :)

Comment: The main drawbacks are applets compared to other systems like HTML5, AJAX and Flash, from my understanding.

Comment: @DasWood - I agree that's the case today. However, Java applets were getting bad press long before HTML5 and when Ajax was still so plagued by JavaScript incompatibilities among browsers that it was not viable as a cross-platform technology. (Microsoft always had their own ideas about the DOM and XML parsing, not to mention function names.) Flash was always a strong competitor to Java, but, unlike Java, generally required investing some actual money for authoring tools.